# pry inspect method not working

Tags: ruby, pry

I have the following code from *understanding computation* book. The intention is to change the `inspect` behavior.

```
class Number < Struct.new(:value)
  def inspect
    "<<#{self}>>"
  end
  def to_s
    value.to_s
  end
end
```

It works as expected when I use `irb`:

```
irb(main):014:0> Number.new(1)
=> <<1>>
```

but it does not when I use `pry`:

```
[8] pry(main)> n = Number.new(1)
=> #<struct Number value=1>
```

The Pry is version 0.10.3 on Ruby 2.0.0. Why does it not work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pry doesn't just use `inspect` to display the return value. It calls a proc called *print object* that is defined in configuration. In `lib/pry.rb`, you can find that it is set to:

```
class Pry
  # The default print
  DEFAULT_PRINT = proc do |output, value, _pry_|
    _pry_.pager.open do |pager|
      pager.print _pry_.config.output_prefix
      Pry::ColorPrinter.pp(value, pager, Pry::Terminal.width! - 1)
    end
  end
end
```

In order to use `inspect` as in `irb`, set it like this as instructed [here](https://github.com/pry/pry/wiki/Customization-and-configuration#Config_print):

```
Pry.config.print = proc {|output, value| output.puts "=> #{value.inspect}"}
```

Then you will get:

```
pry(main)> n = Number.new(1)
=> <<1>>
```

Comment: It seems a shame to modify the printing behavior for all objects (and lose all of Pry's pretty-printing) just to get the behavior you want for one class. Wouldn't adding the class to `Pry.config.prompt_safe_objects`, per the documentation you linked to, accomplish the same thing without the unfortunate side-effects?

Answer (score 1):

Sawa is right in that Pry uses its own printer, but if you look closer at the [source](https://github.com/pry/pry/blob/70bcfa06daf37c37d4fd65da0accd588b06403b4/lib/pry/color_printer.rb#L8) you can see that it actually uses Ruby's `PP` behind the scenes, and `PP` defines its [own behaviour](https://github.com/ruby/pp/blob/30602bccae2554838f694aeaa26f4bcd4016f8ad/lib/pp.rb#L379) for pretty printing Structs:

```rb
class Struct # :nodoc:
  def pretty_print(q) # :nodoc:
    q.group(1, sprintf("#<struct %s", PP.mcall(self, Kernel, :class).name), '>') {
      q.seplist(PP.mcall(self, Struct, :members), lambda { q.text "," }) {|member|
        q.breakable
        q.text member.to_s
        q.text '='
        q.group(1) {
          q.breakable ''
          q.pp self[member]
        }
      }
    }
  end

  def pretty_print_cycle(q) # :nodoc:
    q.text sprintf("#<struct %s:...>", PP.mcall(self, Kernel, :class).name)
  end
end
```

It's worth checking out the [documentation](https://github.com/ruby/pp/blob/30602bccae2554838f694aeaa26f4bcd4016f8ad/lib/pp.rb#L5) (though it is only brief) if you are interested in learning more about this.

So in your struct you could also define your own `pretty_print` and `pretty_print_cycle` methods, which would mean Pry could print these how you want, without having to override their `DEFAULT_PRINT` proc.

Answer (score 0):

I use `Pry` version `0.10.4`.

I've just added the following lines in my `.pryrc` file (I think, that is a *good* 
place for such code):

```
if defined?(BigDecimal)
  BigDecimal.class_eval do
    def inspect
      "<#{to_s('+3F')}>"
    end
  end
end
```

And result:

```
 balance: <+100.0>,
 commission_amount: <+0.15>
```